# Array counter with mimimum find

Tags: data-structures, arrays, amortized-analysis

I need to implement data strucure such as array, but with the following interface:

- **GetMin()** - Returns the minimum from the array
- **IncRight(index)** - Increases all values from specified index to the end of the array by 2
- **DecRight(index)** - Decreases all values from specified index to the end of the array by 2

Assuming that the **datastructure is already initialized**, full of items (which are **integers only**) and we have already minimum found together with its index. So I "only" need to keep track the changes.

My goal is to all operations have **amortized constant time complexity**. The question is: Is it possible at all?

Anyway: How to implement such data structure with **the best time complexity**?

I know one more thing about the initial values: two adjacent values differs only by 1 (plus or minus).

Comment: Is initialized array sorted? How do you access data? After increasing it (or decreasing) how queries look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It is not sorted. But two adjacent values differs only by 1 (plus or minus). I dont know anything about queries, they can be executed in random order and random times. I havent tried so much yet.

Comment: If you haven't tried much yet, it's premature to ask here.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that.  We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755 might be worth reading as well.

Comment: Actually it is part of another problem which I am trying to solve whole day and have not much time for solving, so this is the reason I am asking here for help. Here I posted the default underlaying problem http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64016/correct-bracketing-check-with-rotate-operation-on-position-i. I have tried to solve this subproblem, but it leads me always to linear time. I am wondering if its possible at all (read the question). I dont want for you to post complete solution, just want some hints.

Comment: I think we had a very similar question once... ah, [this one](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/57910/98).

Comment: An impending deadline (I assume for an exercise hand-in) is a reason to overhaul your work process, not to ask on the internet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a post and for advice, Raphael. But how should I overhaul my process? The best think I can do is to keep distance, have a rest and return to the problem after some time, but the only think I havent is the time.

Comment: Feel free to visit [chat] and people might be able to give some suggestions for how to improve your process.  One possible thing that might help would be to start sooner, so you have more time to step away and give your unconscious chance to be creative and come up with ideas for you.